# In Cassandra cql query how to convert string containing timestamp and then using in where clause for time series queries?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In Cassandra table, created_date is string column "2018-04-26 12:59:38 UTC". Need to use this column to create time series query like

```
Select * from dynamic_data where toTimeStamp(created_date) >=? and created_date <=?;
```

Is there any inbuilt function in Cassandra to convert string to timestamp and then use in time series query?